# How to send PDF UL from Django Weasyprint view to display it in HTML Custom

Tags: django, pdftron, weasyprint

I want to display a PDF file in HTML using a custom PDF Viewer (PDFTron Webviewr)

I'm using WeasyTemplateResponseMixin in my view to convert HTML to PDF and send it to the client-side.

but I don't want the PDF to be rendered, I want to send the PDF URL so I can access the PDF URL in the JS function to display it

Is there any of doing that without saving the PDF file, just sending it?

This the view:

```
class BarcodePrint(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, BarcodePrintView):

    pdf_stylesheets = [
    settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/main.css',
     ]
    template_name = 'barcode_print.html'
```

and this is the JS code:

```
generateWebViewr(file){
    WebViewer({
        path: '../../../static/webviewer',
        initialDoc: file ,
      }, document.getElementById('viewer')).then(instance => {
          const { docViewer } = instance;
          docViewer.on('documentLoaded', () => {
            instance.print();

          });
      });
 }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, is the `file` parameter in `generateWebViewr()` method for the URL to the PDF file? You can just pass the URL to the client so that it can display it.

Comment: yes, but how can I pass the URL of the PDF from the backend if I didn't save the PDF?

Comment: You can load the file using other ways, for example from a Blob, see https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/basics/open/blob/ and other options.